# Update text every 3 seconds in the same texline

Tags: javascript, html

I want to toggle the text every 3 seconds in the same text-line.

So far, I have tried the following:

```js
var append3 = document.getElementById('putText3');
var name1 = "john";
var name2 = "elisabetta";
var timeout;
append3.innerHTML += "hi i am" + name1 + ",";
timeout = setTimeout(function () {
    append3.innerHTML += "hi i am" + name2 + ",";
}, 3000);
```

```html
<div id='putText3'><div>
```

This code will give me two seperate lines: "hi i am john" and (after 3000 milliseconds): "hi i am john elisabetta". I want that to change dynamically in the same text area.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion Please explain your answer clearly. also, format your code. https://freeformatter.com/javascript-beautifier.html

Comment: Remove the `+` before `=` in `append3.innerHTML+="hi i am" +name2+",";}, 3000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the information one time with the new text, then it would be a simple matter of changing the "plus-equals" to simply an "equals". As in the following:

```js
var append3 = document.getElementById('putText3');
var name1 = "John";
var name2 = "Elisabetta";
var timeout;
append3.innerHTML += "Hi! I am " + name1 + ",";
timeout = setTimeout(function () {
    append3.innerHTML = "Hi! I am " + name2 + ",";
}, 3000);
```

```html
<div id='putText3'><div>
```

---

If you are repeatedly wanting to toggle every three seconds (as supposed to just one time) then I would suggest the following:

```js
var append3 = document.getElementById('putText3');
var name1 = "John";
var name2 = "Elisabetta";
startCountdownToggle(append3, name1, name2)

function startCountdownToggle(objectToAppend, currentName, nextName) {
  objectToAppend.innerHTML = "Hi, my name is " + currentName + "!";
  var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    startCountdownToggle(objectToAppend, nextName, currentName)
  }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<div id='putText3'>
  <div>
```